# Safari 5 Extension Validating Event

Tags: safari

I want to Validate this toolbar item if there are more than 2 windows open. I know for tabs

> event.target.disabled =
>   event.target.browserWindow.tabs.length
>   < 2;

works.

But

> event.target.disabled =
>   event.target.browserWindows.length <
>   2;

doesn't.

How can I validate so the toolbar item is enabled only if more than one window is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `safari.application.browserWindows.length` instead.